# Why do clients fail to connect to EC2 Application Load Balancer sometimes?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2

**Background**

I have created an dual stack ec2 application load balancer and have configured an A DNS record to point to that application load balancer.

I have an Android/iOS app that connects to that ALB for it's work.

**DNS output**

> dig api-lb-ext.unolo.com

> ; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> api-lb-ext.unolo.com
> ; global options: +cmd
> ;; Got answer:
> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52783
> ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

> ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
> ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
> ;; QUESTION SECTION:
> ;api-lb-ext.unolo.com.      IN  A

> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
> api-lb-ext.unolo.com.   60  IN  A   15.207.81.176
> api-lb-ext.unolo.com.   60  IN  A   13.233.27.203
> api-lb-ext.unolo.com.   60  IN  A   15.206.192.130

> ;; Query time: 52 msec
> ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
> ;; WHEN: Thu Sep 15 15:00:27 IST 2022
> ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 97

**The problem**

99.9% of the time, clients have no issues opening up tcp connections to that application load balancer.

Sometimes however clients fail to connect to the load balancer. I can't be sure if the DNS lookup is failing or if it is failing to connect to my backend services.

**Code structure**

Using the retrofit library on Android (com.squareup.retrofit/1.9.0), we execute a call to my backend API (api-lb-ext.unolo.com).

According to their documentation (https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/connections/), if the DNS lookup they do retrieves multiple results, they loop through each connection until they successfully connect to the backend. Based on **SottoVoce**'s idea in the comments, I will try to see if I can get it to print out the DNS records that it found when it attempted to connect to the backend.

In case of any kind of NETWORK error, I retrieve the ip address of the client (via https://ipv4.jsonip.com/) and print it out to the client. The clients normally just send that screenshot to us, telling us that they can't login to the app.

**What research I have done so far**

I know that the request is not reaching my EC2 ALB instance - I verified this by printing out the IP address on the client side when these errors occur and scanning my EC2 ALB log files for that IP address - not found.

I've also asked the clients for which this error is occurring to change their settings on their Android devices to point to Google's DNS servers in the hope that whatever default DNS server their mobile operator was using was perhaps failing to provide the DNS records - will give back results when the clients come back to me.

**Any patterns in the errors occuring**

None that I can see. Most of my clients connect via mobile data (not WIFI). I know that 99.9% of logins work, however, we get 1-2 support emails a week with this screenshot showing that they were not able to connect to my backend. I know that my services are up and it's working as thousands of other people are able to login at the same time.

**My theories so far**

- My guess is that since the TTL on the A record pointing to my load balancer is very small (60 seconds), we are forcing a DNS lookup every time and perhaps that DNS lookup is failing??

**Guidance required**

Any help on how to try to debug this would be much appreciated..

Comment: "Any help on how to try to debug this would be much appreciated.." How do you know `0.1%` (is that a guessed value?) of clients are not connecting, and what error message do they have then? Any other relevant common facts about clients in error, like same OS version, etc.?

Comment: hi @PatrickMevzek, the 0.1% number is a guesstimate. This error gets shown to the client when they first try to login to my app. If it fails to connect to the backend, then I automatically make a call to https://ipv4.jsonip.com/ to retrieve the ip address of the client and then print out the ip address on the client side. I have updated the original question with the code in question and tried to answer more of the questions that you have.

Comment: A couple of questions:  You wrote "[I] have configured an A DNS record to point to that application load balancer."  What is the DNS record type?  An `A` or `AAAA` record?  A `CNAME` record?  You mention fetching diagnostic info from the Android app.  Can you fetch the IP address the app received after looking up your server's name in DNS, and compare that address with the one(s) the ALB was using at the time of the error?

Comment: hi @SottoVoce, I have configured an `A` record to point to the ec2 load balancer. I have edited the original question with more output from dig to give you a better idea of the output. Regarding your second question, I read further into the documentation of the library we are using (https://square.github.io/okhttp/features/connections/)... when it does a DNS lookup, if it finds that there are multiple matching records, it will loop over all of them until a successful connection is made. I will investigate further to see if I can get it to output the DNS records that it found.

Comment: @psychosk AWS ALBs normally require a dns CNAME record rather than an A record because the load balancer changes its public IP addresses from time to time.  There are some use cases where an "alias" A record in Route 53 works, but generally the documentation recommends CNAME.  Do you think your connection errors may be happening at times the AWS ALB changes IP addresses and your DNS A record still returns the old address?

Comment: Hi @SottoVoce, when I used AWS's Route 53 to configure the routing to the ALB, it automatically picked up the ALB's DNS address (api-lb-ext-2053533142.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com). That address in turn maps to three IP addresses under the covers (as shown by dig), but I don't explicitly control that. That is ALB automagicery. So, IF the public IP address of one of the EC2 instances did change, then ALB should/would be changing the IP addresses that resolve to api-lb-ext-2053533142.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com. Right ?

Comment: And @SottoVoce, yes, I have been able to change our code to print out the IP address that it was trying to connect to when it attempts to login. I am rolling out that release right now and will inform back once I get results.